# Spring request url action class mapping

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, struts

In spring how we map url to action class and function name. 
Is it done through Dispatcherservlet.xml file. As i am a newbie in spring and i have sued struts and webwork before . in that we are specifying the url and particular action class as shown below.

```
<action name="invoiceShow" class="com.org.tcric.action.InvoiceAction" >             
<result name="success" type="dispatcher">
<param name="location">purchase/somefile.jsp</param> 
</result> 
</action>
```

How this can be done in spring through xml and which file? When i google iam a little bit confused , i dont want annotation based solution instead i want to use XML.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>demo</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>   <servlet-mapping> <servlet-name>demo</servlet-name>    
     <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>  </servlet-mapping>
```

Here or all the request preceeding .html extension would be delegated to DispatcherServlet. Later you can define @Controller class with @RequestMapping("/one.html") to delegate a particular request to a particular method.

Comment: Can we do this @requestmapping through xml? that is what i asked

Comment: You can do it in dispatcher-servlet.xml file as   <bean name="/extending.html" class="yourPackage.YourController">

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the same way you do it in struts. On the web.xml where you define the entry point for urls, a DispatcherServlet of Spring would be delegated to accept the request for urls.

Comment: could you please add a piece of code like that i have added in the question.